# Can I use Spring Cloud Gateway for role based authorization?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-gateway

I have several microservices in my architecture. I want to implement an API Gateway to route request to services. To achieve that, I implement `spring-cloud-gateway` and this is my `application.yml`

```
server:
  port: 9090
spring:
  application:
  name: "API-GATEWAY"
  cloud:
   gateway:
    routes:
      - id: task-service
        uri: 'http://localhost:8083'
        predicates:
          - Path=/task/**
```

So far everything works as expected. a request `localhost:9090/task/123` is to `localhost:8083/task/123`. Here comes to second part.

I want some users access to only some endpoints. In my JWT token, I have role field.

```
  {
      "accountName": "erdem.ontas",
      "surname": "Öntaş",
      "roles": [
        "ADMIN",
        "USER"
      ],
}
```

I don't want specify authorization in every service separately, is there any way to specify role based access in spring-cloud-gateway? For example I want USER role to be able to access to `GET http://localhost:9090/task/` but not to `GET http://localhost:9090/dashboard/`

Comment: I think one of possible solutions is to write custom predicate/filter. Articles for it: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-custom-gateway-filters and https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-routing-predicate-factories

Answer (score 8):

If you do **not** want and need to create full OAuth 2 Server/Client infrastructure and want to keep it simple just create a custom `GatewayFilter` in which just check if the JWT token extracted from the header has the preconfigured roles.
So start with a simple `GatewayFilter`

```
@Component
public class RoleAuthGatewayFilterFactory extends
        AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<RoleAuthGatewayFilterFactory.Config> {

    public RoleAuthGatewayFilterFactory() {
        super(Config.class);
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            var request = exchange.getRequest();
            // JWTUtil can extract the token from the request, parse it and verify if the given role is available
            if(!JWTUtil.hasRole(request, config.getRole())){
                // seems we miss the auth token
                var response = exchange.getResponse();
                response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
                return response.setComplete();
            }
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        };
    }

    @Data
    public static class Config {
        private String role;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> shortcutFieldOrder() {
        // we need this to use shortcuts in the application.yml
        return Arrays.asList("role");
    }
}
```

Here we just create a simple filter which receives the required role from the config (application.yml) and checks if the request is authorized to continue.

To use the filter just add `filters` into you route config.

```
server:
  port: 9090
spring:
  application:
  name: "API-GATEWAY"
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: task-service
          uri: 'http://localhost:8083'
          filters:
            - RoleAuth=ADMIN
          predicates:
            - Path=/task/**
```

So this way the `RoleAuth` filter can be reused over the several routes.

Comment: Hello, where is your JWTUtil class? I would like to know the implementation.

Comment: @AbhijitMondalAbhi look into https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt project

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Is it the same project which you described above? I did not find the application.yml file. As well as I did not find any Spring Boot Cloud Gateway Project. I basically need the JWTUtil class where you checking the hasRole(). @Babl